# Change width of UIButton with constraints within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a button in a tableViewCell but I cannot shrink it to fit its titleLabel, which is smaller than the button is. The button seems to have a minimum frame. When I deleted all its constraints within the cell, I could change its size again. But how do I supposed to shrink it while having these constraints?

The button - "subjectButton" - in the cell

[image]

Constrains of "subjectButton":

[image]

My attempt:

```
func setButtonStyle(_ button: UIButton, subject: String) {
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    button.setTitle(subject, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    button.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 5, height: 20)
}
```

Simulator (with "Colored Blended Layers" turned on):

[image]

As you can see, the button does not shrink to fit its titleLabel by using `button.sizeToFit`. Also, I failed to manually resize it by using `button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 5, height: 20)`.

Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please remove the width constrain. Then try and please remove the label title from the attribute inspector then try to shrink the width. maybe this would be helpful.

Comment: call the function in cell for row

Comment: Please remove width constraint or create a width constant in application and dynamically change there constraint

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia I tried. I added the width constraint after I met the problem. I saw some similar problems and that’s what one answer suggested. Didn’t work.

Comment: okay. is there button is inside any View or StackView?

Comment: @BrahamYoussef Yes, I did that in cell for row.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia No. Its superView is the cell.

Comment: @BhumeshPurohit I tried to use `button.frame.size.width = 10`. It didn't work. The button in each cell now has a fixed width, not changed to 10.

Comment: what you put in the subject label in second one attached image.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia  I put “CHEMISTRY”. The button stretches it self to fit it perfectly.

Comment: `I cannot shrink it to fit its titleLabel` you want the subject label Right? and you take the `UIButton` in the cell instead of label. Is that Correct or any mistake?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia  It is a button. So I take the button. It’s called subjectButton. I mean to shrink the button to fit subjectButton.titleLabel.

Comment: if possible share the project. so can get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Create Your Constaint @property IBOutlet Like

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *height;
```

after Change there height like

```
self.height.constant = button.frame.size.height + 15;
```

Comment: Didn't work but thank you very much for all the kind support :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.titleLabel?.frame.width ?? 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: Kindly, add the description so other readers can view and understand easily, thank you.